# Double artifact resolution in Maven/Assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

We are using Maven **3.0.5** and assembly plugin **2.2-beta-3**.

When we got a transitive range dependency we got an issue that during compile and assembly stage different versions were resolved (we had version X in manifest in the jar and version Y put into tar.gz assembly package).

**Question**: Is it possible to avoid duplicate artifact resolution in compile+assembly steps so assembly will use the same artifacts as resolved by compilation?

**UPD**: Saw the same issue with assembly 2.6, probably will try to build a minimal example for it.

Comment: Any reason why using such an old version of assembly plugin (and of maven as well)?

Comment: Use uptodate plugin versions see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/ and use those versions...If you have further issues please mail on the users list or in case you think you found a bug please file in a jira ticket. The current version is 2.6 !

Answer (score 1):

You are using a really old version of the `maven-assembly-plugin`, version `2.2-beta-3` is from [**2009**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY/fixforversion/12330348/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel).

Many similar issues have been resolved since then, just to mention some:

- [**MASSEMBLY-448**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-448): Assembly plugin's dependency resolution for dependency sets is not inline with maven dependency resolution
- [**MASSEMBLY-432**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-432): assembly misapplies depMgt and selects the wrong dependency for an archive
- [**MASSEMBLY-299**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-299): assembly does not honnor `<dependencyManagement>` directives

So, I would strongly recommend to upgrade it to at least non-beta version, the released **2.2**.

A newer version of Maven and a newer version of the assembly plugin would be the ideal solution, but it really depends on your hard constraints on these versioning, if any.

Comment: 2.2 is also very old...don't use such old versions. See my comment above.

Comment: @A. Di Matteo thanks for suggestion, looks like the issue is with outdated versions so we will try to update it and check again. The remaining question is - do you know is it possible to avoid duplicate resolution by compile/assembly stages?

Comment: @khmarbaise I agree, as I stated at the bottom of the answer, both maven and plugin should be upgraded, but we don't know why these old versions were used (if any real/hard reason exists), so at least as bare minimal suggestion, I would say don't use beta versions. Then, we are definitely aligned, avoid also using released versions from 2009 and try to push for newer.

Comment: Sure. The problem is related to many old posts which reference those old versions which are copy&pasted...;-)

Comment: @dbf the plugin needs to resolve the (transitive) dependencie to pack them in a jar with dependencies, for example, but resolution would be against the local repository anyway (unless bugs for mismatching resolution). check [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10780503/5606016) for similar issue. Solution was to move to `maven-shade-plugin`, which is the recommended approach anyway in most cases.

Comment: Have the same issue with 2.6, will try to build a small example.